# explanation for more than one jdwp port for android process

Tags: android, debugging, jpda, jdwp

I am trying to debug android application using Jdb and other debuggers which use socket type of connector to connect to debuggee process. I know that we can forward jdwp port of process to local tcp port using `adb jdwp` and `adb forward tcp:xxx jdwp:yyyy` command and attach debugger. But during testing I have realised some processes return more than one jdwp port. So my question is what do those additional jdwp ports corresponds to or why is there more than one jdwp port for a single process ? And how to debug these kind of applications ?